# C - access memory directly using address?

Tags: c, memory-access

I've been lightly studying C for a few weeks now with some book.

```
int main(void)
{
    float num = 3.15;
    int *ptr = (int *)&num; //so I can use line 8 and 10

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (!(i % 8) && (i / 8))
            printf(" ");
        printf("%d", *ptr >> (31 - i) & 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
output : 01000000 01001001 10011001 10011010
```

As you see `3.15` in single precision `float` is `01000000 01001001 10011001 10011010`.
So let's say `ptr` points to address `0x1efb40`.

**Here are the questions:**

1. As I understood in the book, first 8 bits of `num` data is stored in `0x1efb40`, 2nd 8 bits in `0x1efb41`, next 8 bits in `0x1efb42` and last 8 bits in `0x1efb43`. Am I right?
2. If I'm right, is there any way I can directly access the 2nd 8 bits with hex address value `0x1efb41`? Thereby can I change the data to something like `11111111`?

Comment: This is undefined behavior as it breaks strict aliasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote is not actually valid C.  C has a rule called "strict aliasing," which states that if a region of memory contains a value of one type (i.e. `float`), it cannot be accessed as though it was another type (i.e. `int`).  This rule has its origins in some performance optimizations that let the compiler generate faster code.  I can't say it's an obvious rule, but it's the rule.

You can work around this by using `union`.  If you make a union like `union { float num, int numAsInt }`, you can store a float and then read it as an integer.  The result is *unspecified*.  Alternatively, you are always permitted to access the bytes of a value as chars (just not anything larger).  `char` is given special treatment (presumably to make it so you can copy a buffer of data as bytes, then cast it to your data's type and access it, which is something that happens a lot in low level code like network stacks).

Welcome to a fun corner of learning C.  There's *unspecified* behavior and *undefined* behavior.  Informally, unspecified behavior says "we won't say what happens, but it will be reasonable."  The C spec will not say what order the bytes are in.  But it will say that you will get some bytes.  Undefined behavior is nastier.  Undefined behavior says *anything* can happen, ranging from compiler errors to exceptions at runtime, to absolutely nothing at all (making you think your code is valid when it is not).

As for the values, dbush points out in his answer that the order of the bytes is defined by the platform you are on.  You are seeing a "little endian" representation of a IEE754 floating point number.  On other platforms, it may be different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had confusion in the questions above and I found the answer was endianness. When I added line " char *ptr2 = (char *)&num; " at the end and checked the output with integer type it always gave me -102 whereas I expected 64(0100000 in binary). It actually pointed the fourth 8 bits(10011010). Problem solved :)

Answer (score 4):

The ordering of bytes within a datatype is known as **endianness** and is system specific.  What you describe with the least significant byte (LSB) first is called **little endian** and is what you would find on x86 based processors.

As for accessing particular bytes of a representation, you can use a pointer to an `unsigned char` to point to the variable in question to view the specific bytes.  For example:

```
 float num = 3.15;
 unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&num;
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<sizeof(num); i++) {
     printf("byte %d = %02x\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

Note that this is only allowed to access bytes via a character pointer, not an `int *`, as the latter violates strict aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Union punning is much safer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef     union
    {
        unsigned char uc[sizeof(double)];
        float f;
        double d;
    }u_t;

void print(u_t u, size_t size, int endianess)
{
    size_t start = 0;
    int increment = 1;

    if(endianess)
    {
        start = size - 1;
        increment = -1;
    }

    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        printf("%hhx ", u.uc[start]);
        start += increment;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void) 
{
    u_t u;  
    u.f = 3.15f;

    print(u, sizeof(float),0);
    print(u, sizeof(float),1);

    u.d = 3.15;
    print(u, sizeof(double),0);
    print(u, sizeof(double),1);
    return 0;
}
```

you can test it yourself: https://ideone.com/7ABZaj